# Copy data range but ignore (not copy) cells with formula and paste to last row in another sheet. Below script was working, but now

Tags: google-apps-script, copy-paste

I was using the following script in order to copy data from one sheet to another in the same spreadsheet with values only and in a specific cell.

My problem is that now the script is not correctly working. When I check the sheet where the values are copied, there has been made error like "Spreadsheets". I don't know what is exactly wrong and how to fix that code.
Maybe it is on the last row of scripts.

I would really appreaciate your help. Thank you!!

```
function Movedata1() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Receipt");
      var range = sh.getRange("B12:W44");
      var values = range.getValues();
      var dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Historical Receipts");
      dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
      };
```

Comment: I think that your script works when the sheet names are correct. So, in order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the detail of `error like "Spreadsheets"`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's showing Exception: Server error: Spreadsheets. macros.gs.7. I don't actually know what exact error is.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, for example, when you create a new Google Spreadsheet and test it again, what result will you obtain?

Comment: I created new spreadsheets and ran that script again as you said. I think my data contains image and all errors are connected with images I guess. How can I copy and paste images normally. Images were exported like _uc export=view&id=_ mode.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, what is `Images were exported like uc export=view&id= mode.`? Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation?

Comment: Oh sorry, I made mistake that how images are exported. Image's formula is being like image(), and error is connected that. How could I copy & paste images correctly?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following reply,

> I made mistake that how images are exported. Image's formula is being like image(), and error is connected that.

From this, I thought that the reason for your issue is due to the inner image in a cell. In this case, how about using `copyTo` instead of `setValues`? The modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function Movedata1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Receipt");
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Historical Receipts");
  var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("B12:W44");
  var dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  srcRange.copyTo(dstRange); // or srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

#### References:

- [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)
- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Comment: Thanks for your new script. That script is copying and pasting all the range of cells which have formulas. Could you please modify that I can copy only cells with data from the range and paste its values to another sheet?

Comment: @Ashley Houston Thank you for replying. About `That script is copying and pasting all the range of cells which have formulas. Could you please modify that I can copy only cells with data from the range and paste its values to another sheet?`, when you tested `srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, { contentsOnly: true });` instead of `srcRange.copyTo(dstRange);`, is that your expected result?

Comment: Wow, It works. Thanks for your  so much effort. It was my fault that I tested only `srcRange.copyTo(dstRange)` script instead of `srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, { contentsOnly: true })`. Thank you so much :))

Comment: @Ashley Houston Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, @Tanaike. I need your help to copy and paste script above. There are variable rows of data in the range of B12:W44. There might be 2 or 20 rows of data. If there are 2 rows of data, there are 2 rows with values and 31 blank rows in the target range after I run the code. How to copy and paste only cells with data? So much blank rows in the target range :((

Comment: @Ashley Houston About your new question, I would like to support you. But your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't mind that I need to post it as a new question :))